# JS: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in browser console when using <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have an array defined in PHP:

```
$outofstock = array ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 );
$_SESSION['outofstock']=$outofstock;
```

I try to pass it to a JS script this way:

```
var outofstock = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['outofstock']); ?>;
```

and I get an error with execution stop:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'                VM563 newhed14.39.js:1

The same statement works in another script within an HTML file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: make sure the session is started on that page first, second just use `json_encode` so that you get the array equivalent compatible to js

Comment: Are you writing that directly in your javascript file, or in your PHP code that will then send the javascript to the client? If you include ````var outofstock = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['outofstock']); ?>;```` directly in javascript it will have an error, but if ````var outofstock = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['outofstock']); ?>;```` is run in PHP, it will replace the middle with valid javascript prior to being run.

Comment: You need to pass a `single quotes` before and after define `php` code in script eg:`var outofstock = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['outofstock']); ?>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is that "PHP scripts do not run in .js files". you need to do this:

in your HTML document:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myArray" value="<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['outofstock']); ?>">
```

then you can access this array in js like this:

```
var array = document.getElementById('myArray').value;
console.log(array)
```

from this way you access your PHP array in your js. hope it helps ...

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your file is named `newhed14.39.js` suggests to me that you're serving this particular file as a .js file statically, rather than through PHP. This means that PHP will not run - the PHP commands will end up literally in the file and will thus obviously end up as syntax errors. It's easy enough to check if this is the case - just open up the developer console on your browser and take a look at the file which threw the error; the PHP commands should be visible there (whereas they shouldn't be if PHP had processed the file).

The solution would be to move the variable into the dynamic output generated by a PHP script in a `<script>` tag, and to edit your JS to consume that variable (for example, by having the `<script>` tag call a function defined in the `.js` file).